# Different formats for size and location properties

Tags: c#, .net, windows, reflection

I have created a program in C# that uses XML files to load controls. I use reflection to load and present the controls. This program is used on multiple Windows platforms in Europe and USA.
After a Windows update in a computer in USA, it seems the format for Size and Location has changed. I've always used the format "32;32" to specify width and height. Location uses the same format to specify X and 
Y coordinates. 
Now suddenly the notation has changed on this single computer so it has to use the format "32,32", ie a comma instead of a semicolon. This relates to both Location and Size and any other property that takes multiple values. This means I have to change hundreds of settings to reflect the new format, or find out why the format changed.
I suspect there's a setting in Windows to control this, but where can I find it?

Comment: Turns out this has to do with the regional settings in Windows. Specifically the List Separator setting. For some reason this setting was changed in the last Windows update, so after I changed it back my program worked as expected.

Comment: The list separator is *supposed* to be `,` for US (and also UK) regions.

Comment: Indeed. But here (in Sweden) we're using ´;´. So it gets confusing when you have an app running in different regions with different settings. It works perfectly in one region but not at all in another, because of this difference. And I don't want to change hundreds of parameter files just because of this, so the easy fix was to just change the setting in Windows.